# instagram scrapping: hashtag from other user's post

Tags: instagram

imma encountering JSON Query to graphql/query: HTTP error code 401. [retrying; skip with ^C] when trying to scrape and ranking frequency of hashtags used in other users' post (eg: my competitor's ig). How should I fix it and prevent this from happening again?

Many thanks for helping me

trying to scrape and ranking frequency of hashtags used in other users' post

```
import instaloader

bot = instaloader.Instaloader()

profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(bot.context, 'prepvn')

posts = profile.get_posts()

hashtag_frequency = {}
total_posts = 0

for post in posts:
    total_posts += 1
    for tag in post.caption_hashtags:
        if tag not in ['ignore1', 'ignore2', 'ignore3']:
            if tag in hashtag_frequency:
                hashtag_frequency[tag] += 1
            else:
                hashtag_frequency[tag] = 1

# Sắp xếp theo tần suất xuất hiện (giảm dần)
sorted_hashtags = sorted(hashtag_frequency.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

# Giới hạn số lượng hashtag in ra
max_hashtags = 30
count = 0

# Tạo file CSV và ghi kết quả
filename = 'hashtag_frequency.csv'
with open(filename, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['Hashtag', 'Frequency']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    for hashtag, frequency in sorted_hashtags:
        if count < max_hashtags:
            writer.writerow({'Hashtag': hashtag, 'Frequency': frequency})
            count += 1
        else:
        break
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! If want some help, please post the code you have first, otherwise people can't help you, because we have no idea what you're currently doing. At a glance, a 401 error code says that you are unauthorised - you may need to send through some credentials through whatever request you are making.

Comment: From googling "instaloader" and going onto their github page, you can see that you are not the only one with this issue ( https://github.com/instaloader/instaloader/issues/2071 , logged a couple of hours ago). It is probably a change made by instagram to deter scrapers. You are more likely to get help on instaloader's github page rather than here on stack overflow.